# Tipo de dato genérico en java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

la verdad no sé mucho acerca de esto pero quiero saber cómo tener una clase que acepte cualquier tipo de dato como parámetro. 
He visto que lo que quiero hacer se usa en un ArrayList por ejemplo de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<String> arreglo=new ArrayList();
```

O también:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arreglo=new ArrayList();
```

El array list puede guardar cualquier tipo de dato que el usuario le indique.

Cómo tener una clase que al crear el objeto también se le indique el tipo de dato con el que va a trabajar.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que puedas crear un objeto con cualquier tipo de dato?

Comment: A lo que te refieres se llama *genéricos*, y puedes encontrar un tutorial al respecto aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/, y puedes encontrar un ejemplo de cómo crear una clase con genéricos aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html. Si tienes una duda mas específica, puedes agregar detalles al respecto en tu pregunta.

Comment: @Dev.Joel El tipo de dato Object no es s:

Comment: @sstan Gracias por el enlace es lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: A mi sí me parece una pregunta válida y le doy mi voto

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Qué significa <X> delante del nombre de una función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171566/qu%c3%a9-significa-x-delante-del-nombre-de-una-funci%c3%b3n)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Qué significa el comando ArrayList<Integer>(); al crear un ArrayList?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39517/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-comando-arraylistinteger-al-crear-un-arraylist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Moviendo mi comentario a una respuesta para que no quede la pregunta abierta innecesariamente)*

A lo que te refieres se llama **genéricos**, y puedes encontrar un tutorial al respecto aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics.

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo de cómo crear una clase con genéricos aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html.

Sacado de ese último enlace:

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

En este ejemplo la sintaxis `class Box<T>` es la que te permite definir un parámetro de tipo genérico `T` que puede aceptar cualquier tipo. Con ese ejemplo, es posible usar la clase `Box` de las siguientes formas:

```
Box<String> boxString = new Box();
boxString.set("abc");    

Box<Integer> boxInteger = new Box();
boxInteger.set(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una muy buena respuesta que habla sobre generics, lo unico que agregaria es que cuando haces este tipo de cosas es muy importante agregar compareTo y equals para que el usuario tenga elementos como para por ejemplo ordenarlos en una lista.

Answer (score -1):

el tipo generico es Object, pero no es recomendable usarlo, ya que admite de todo, puede acarrear problemas.

```
ArrayList<Object> arreglo=new ArrayList<>();
```

la coleccion arreglo puede almacenar numeros, cadenas, objetos

Comment: por que -1? justifiquese