# Qué significa el comando ArrayList<Integer>(); al crear un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente comando

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new // crea un ArrayList
      ArrayList<Integer>();**  // ¿Que está haciendo de nuevo esta línea?
```

Comment: ¿Qué dificultad tienes con esa línea que indicas? Está invocando al constructor de `ArrayList` que no recibe argumentos.

Comment: Si la línea  ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new

Comment: El `new` por sí solo no hace nada. La sentencia es `new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

Comment: @saeta lo correcto debe ser: // crea un ArrayList
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new  ArrayList<Integer>();

Answer (score 9):

Considerando el siguiente trozo de código:

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Este se compone de varias partes, pero se escribe normalmente como una sola linea.

**Primero** se declara el tipo con

```
ArrayList<T>
```

Esto quiere decir que se tiene la intención de declarar una variable del tipo `ArrayList`. En Java es obligatorio que se declare el tipo de variable, esto debido a que java es un [lenguaje tipado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte). Por otro lado, [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) es una clase que representa un tipo de [estructura de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructura_de_datos) que es común en programación, llamadas [Listas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada). 
Ahora, los signos `<>` que están a la derecha del tipo, se llaman coloquialmente *diamantes*. Estos quieren decir que la clase `ArrayList` hace uso de [parámetros genéricos](https://www.luaces-novo.es/genericos-para-recien-llegados-a-java/). Los tipos genéricos permiten a la clase que hace uso de estas estructuras (ArrayList), abstraerse del funcionamiento interno de `t`. Entonces `t` solo implementa los métodos que la clase que hace uso del tipo genérico, necesita para manipularlos. En este caso no se necesita que `t` implemente métodos especiales, por lo tanto se puede declarar de cualquier tipo que sea un ejemplar de Object ( `t extends Object` )([Ver Herencia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)). Ej:

```
ArrayList<String>
ArrayList<Integer>
ArrayList<Perro>
```

Puedes ver mas información desde la documentación oficial en inglés: [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

**Segundo**, se da nombre a la variable con:

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures
```

Cada [variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) debe tener un nombre conforme a las [reglas de nombres en Java](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Variables). También existen distintos [tipos de variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Esta podría solo ser una declaración si se cierra la instrucción con `;` .

**Tercero**. Se usa el [operador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `=` para asignar un valor a la variable que se acaba de declarar. Esto se puede hacer tanto en la misma linea como en una nueva. Ej:

```
int numero;
numero = 1;
```

o también

```
int numero = 1;
```

**Cuarto.** Se crea un ejemplar de la clase con `new`. El operador `new` reserva memoria para el nuevo objeto de la derecha, [su sintaxis es](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):

> new [nombre del constructor]([parámetros del constructor])

Esto produce una llamada al [constructor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(inform%C3%A1tica)) de esa clase y devuelve una referencia a el nuevo ejemplar de la misma, cabe destacar que siempre el constructor de una clase lleva el nombre de la misma. Las clases que poseen constructores privados no se pueden ejemplarizar ([Modificadores de acceso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html))

Finalmente una clase se puede ejemplarizar con un tipo diferente si son parte de la misma jerarquía de clases ([Herencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herencia_(inform%C3%A1tica))).

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> weeklyTemperatures = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

El código anterior lo que significa es que estás creando una variable llamada `weeklyTemperatures`, que es de tipo `ArrayList<Integer>`.

O sea, una lista de números enteros. Y estás inicializando su valor con la llamada al constructor de la clase `ArrayList`.

Si tienes dudas con esto, te recomiendo varios tutoriales que existen en internet relacionados con la programación orientada a objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Java ArrayList. Estructura dinámica de datos

Un array al que se le pueden asignar elementos de distinto puede tener alguna complicación a la hora de trabajar con él. Por eso, una alternativa a esta declaración es indicar el tipo de objetos que contiene. En este caso, el array solo podrá contener objetos de ese tipo.

De forma general:

```
ArrayList<tipo> nombreArray = new ArrayList<tipo>();
```

tipo debe ser una clase. Indica el tipo de objetos que contendrá el array.
No se pueden usar tipos primitivos. Para un tipo primitivo se debe utilizar su clase envolvente.

Por ejemplo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Crea el array numeros de enteros.

Answer (score 1):

El comando `ArrayList<Integer>` forma parte de la sentencia que se utiliza para construir un objeto de tipo `ArrayList` de números enteros (`Integer`).

En el código de la pregunta está bien escrito, aunque separado en dos líneas, debería funcionar sin ningún problema, pero ojo, **los dos asteriscos del final sí que son un error**. Supongo que son un error de escritura en el código y no debería aparecer en tu código si quieres que funcione.