# ¿Por qué no es posible usar un tipo primitivo como argumento?

Tags: java

Intenté en mi codigo utilizar un tipo primitivo como argumento de una lista.

```
List<int> list = ... //int n’est pas un sous-type d’objet
```

Pero parece que es ilegal et que es necesario utilizar un Objeto

```
List<Integer> list = ...
```

¿Por qué no es posible usar un tipo primitivo como argumento?

Comment: Aquí la respuesta a tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39517/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-comando-arraylistinteger-al-crear-un-arraylist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las clases genéricas no pueden ser parametrizadas a tipos primitivos.
Para resolver este problema el lenguaje define clases envoltorio de los tipos primitivos:
 `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Character`, `Boolean`, etc.

El compilador transforma automáticamente tipos primitivos en clases envoltorio y viceversa:

```
List<Integer> list = ...
list.add(12)
list.add(new Integer(12))
```

Answer (score 6):

Lo que intentas no es posible porque en Java, el tipo de cualquier variable es un tipo primitivo o un tipo de referencia. Los argumentos de tipo genérico deben ser tipos de referencia. Dado que los primitivos no extienden de `Object`, no pueden utilizarse como argumentos de tipo genérico para un tipo parametrizado.

Por eso con [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/lang/Integer.html) funciona, porque sí extiende de `Object`, mientras que `int` es primitivo.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Y, desde Java 7 puedes hacer esto:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Sin embargo hay que señalar que con el [autoboxing en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), el tipo primitivo `int` se convertirá en un `Integer` cuando sea necesario.

Autoboxing es la conversión automática que realiza el compilador de Java entre los tipos primitivos y sus correspondientes clases de envoltorios de objetos.

Por eso esto es válido:

```
int myInt = 1;
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
list.add (myInt);

System.out.println (list.get (0)); // imprime 1
```

---

- Fuente: [Create a List of primitive int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021276/5587982)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar arrayList para ese propósito de la siguiente manera:

```
Arraylist <Integer> enterosLista = new Arraylist<>();
```

No puedes declarar un Lista como un array, por ejemplo:

```
int []UnArray  = {1,2,3}
```

Debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Arraylist <Integer> enterosLista = new Arraylist<>();
List <Integer> enterosLista = new Arraylist<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Las clases genericas en java esperan un objeto que extiendan de `Object`, los tipos de datos primitivos como ser `int, long, char`, etc, no extienden del mismo.

`Integer` es un wrapper del tipo primitovo `int`

Answer (score 1):

Un objeto es una cosa distinta a un tipo primitivo, aunque contengan la misma información. Tener siempre presente que los objetos en Java (**Integer**) tienen un tipo de tratamiento y los tipos primitivos (**int**), otro. Que en un momento dado contengan la misma información no significa en ningún caso que sean lo mismo.

Aquí una lectura sobre la diferencia entre [Tipos de dato primitivos y clases](http://www.edu4java.com/es/java/tipos-de-dato-primitivos-clases.html)