# Qué significa <X> delante del nombre de una función

Tags: java, genericos

He visto que se puede definir una función así :

```
private static <X> Clase <X> {

}
```

¿Qúe significa esa `<X>` del principio?

Comment: Eso no es una función, es la definición de una clase.

Comment: El `<X>` significa que la clase es genérica y que puede ser aplicada  a varios tipos: int, double, String, etc. Mirate este tutorial https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2016/04/tutorial-sobre-los-tipos-genericos-de-java/

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez tienes que usar clases no tipos. No te va a funcionar con int pero si con Integer

Comment: Tienes razón, debí haber mencionado las clases. Espero que se lea el tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una función así es declarada para poder ser aplicada a cualquier tipo de dato que deseemos. Como la función es estática no se puede obtener el genérico de la instancia declarada.

Por ejemplo, imagina que queremos simplemente devolver los elementos de una lista que están en la posición impar:

```
List<String> palabras = ...
List<Integer> numeros = ...

List<String> impares = posicionesImpares(palabras);
```

Para crear esta función, necesitas recibir una List de cualquier tipo, sin genéricos sería tan sencillo como

```
//Java 1.4, back to 2003!
public static List posicionesImpares(List lista) { ...}
```

Pero si queremos evitar los avisos del compilador, y aplicamos genéricos, tendríamos que hacer algo como

```
public static <T> List<T> posicionesImpares(List<T> lista) {...}
```

Te preguntarás *¿Por qué hay que escribir tres veces `<T>`?*. La razón es la siguiente: T no es una clase, es un *tipo genérico*, por tanto si escribiéramos

```
public static List<T> posicionesImpares(List<T> lista) {...} //error
```

El compilador diría que T no es una clase/interfaz conocida, no está definida a nivel de la clase a la que pertenece este método estático.

Por tanto, puedes leer la declaración de la función como:

> Dado un tipo T, el método posicionesImpares recibe una lista de instancias de T y devuelve una lista de instancias de T.

Por supuesto, T podría estar delimitado :

```
//Solo admitimos comparables
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> posicionesImpares(List<T> lista) {...}
```

El caso que has puesto en particular no saca ningún provecho de los genéricos, puesto que no los usa:

```
//Válido, pero R no aporta nada y sencillamente será eliminado por el compilador
public static < R > int getRespuesta(){ return 8; }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Todo mucho más claro :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios tipos de metodos en Java, en esta respuesta me centraré en 2:

```
public static Obj ejemplo1(){
  return objeto;
}
public static void ejemplo1();
```

A groso modo, la única diferencia que hay es que en el primer método, devolveremos un objeto de la clase Obj.

Obj puede ser: String, Integer, BigDecimal, String[], Array, ArrayList< Objeto >, etc....

Dependiendo de el tipo que sea, devolverá un tipo de objeto u otro.

En este ejemplo, le solicitamos al metodo 'queDiaEsHoy()' que nos devuelva un 'Date'.

```
private static Date queDiaEsHoy(){
  return newDate();
}
```

En el siguiente ejemplo, no nos devolverá nada ya que es 'void' pero pintará en consola "Buenos días"

```
private void pintarBuenosDias(){
  System.out.println("Buenos días");
}
```

En este, me centro en la duda que tu planteas:

```
private static ArrayList<String> devolverArray(){
  ArrayList<String> ejemplo = new ArrayList<String>();
  ejemplo.add("parte 1 del array");
  ejemplo.add("parte 2 del array");

  return ejemplo; //←Devolvemos un ArrayList de tipo string
}
```

El método `devolverArray()` se llamaría tal que así:

```
//  
ArrayList<String> arrayString = null;  
arrayString = devolverArray();  
//
```

Comment: Creo que me he explicado mal. El método viene definido de la siguiente forma:

`private static **< R >** Respuesta getRespuesta(){
     ....
}`