# Métodos estáticos con un argumento genérico

Tags: java, java-8

¡Saludos!

Mi duda es la siguiente:
En un proyecto de Java, en concreto una ETL, tengo clases que representan el viejo esquema de la base de datos origen y clases que representan el nuevo esquema de la base destino. En clases aparte se realizan las consultas y transformaciones entre las anteriores, además de esto, se deben guardar los elementos de el viejo modelo y el nuevo modelo (que son almacenados en Vectores) para poder recuperarlos, ya que a veces se corre sólo parcialmente...

Mi problema es que para cada clase del viejo modelo y del nuevo, debo escribir un método "guardarEnArchivo" y "leerDesdeArchivo" que pintan más o menos así:

```
public void guardarEnArchivo(Vector<nombreDeMiClase> toSave, File archivo){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for(int i=0; i<toSave.size(); i++) {
            oos.writeObject(toSave.elementAt(i));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) { try { oos.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
        if (fos != null) { try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
    }
}
public Vector<nombreDeMiClase> leerDesdeArchivo(File archivo) {
    Vector<nombreDeMiClase> toLoad = new Vector<nombreDeMiClase>();
    nombreDeMiClase tmp;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        do {
            tmp = (nombreDeMiClase) ois.readObject();
            if (tmp != null) {
                toLoad.addElement(tmp);
            }
            
        } while (tmp != null);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) { try { ois.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
        if (fis != null) { try { fis.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
    }
    
  return toLoad;
}
```

He intentado generar un método estático que pueda escribir vectores de objetos de cualquier tipo, y uno que pueda leerlos de la misma manera, para no tener que repetir el código cambiando únicamente nombreDeMiClase... Pero tengo errores al momento de pasar los parámetros (el tipo del Vector) y de hacer el cast (en el leerDesdeArchivo)... Hasta el momento, logré generalizar el método guardarEnArchivo con el siguiente cambio:

`public static void guardarEnArchivo (Vector<?> toSave, File archivo)`

Pero no doy con la parte de la lectura... ¿Alguien me podría iluminar?

De antemano, muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Vector... ese es un nombre que no había leído en mucho tiempo.

Comment: Qué te puedo decir... Me sigue agradando más que ArrayList jeje

Comment: Vector no se usa porque es más lento en ejecución que ArrayList y las ventajas que aporta son marginales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los métodos estáticos necesitas "declarar" el genérico de antemano, como si fuera una instancia. Creo que te funcionaría si cambias la firma de los métodos a

```
public <T> void guardarEnArchivo(List<T> toSave, File archivo){
    // ...
}
```

y a

```
public <T> List<T> leerDesdeArchivo(File archivo) {
    // ...
}
```

La razón para esta sintaxis la puedes encontrar en [esta otra pregunta / respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171566/qu%C3%A9-significa-x-delante-del-nombre-de-una-funci%C3%B3n/)

Comment: Eres mi héroe @Pablo, muchísimas gracias... Finalmente quedó resuelto aplicando los genéricos... Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta y por tu tiempo.
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es una clara aplicación de herencia de clases.

Crea una clase mas (el padre) y haces que `nombreDeMiClase` (el hijo) herede de ella (para aprovechar esto podrías considerar que miembros puede tener la clase padre que son comúnes en todos sus hijos, esto se llama generalización)
Un ejemplo:

```
public class PadreDeMiClase {
   /*Miembros*/
}

public class nombreDeMiClase extends PadreDeMiClase {
   /*Miembros*/
}
```

Al tener esto, todas tus otras clases, es decir, todas tus nuevas `nombreDeMiClase` heredaran de `PadreDeMiClase`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class nombreDeMiClase2 extends PadreDeMiClase {
   /*Miembros*/
}

public class nombreDeMiClase3 extends PadreDeMiClase {
   /*Miembros*/
}
```

El truco de todo es hacer que tus funciones tengan vectores parametrizados con `PadreDeMiClase`, y como entiendo que estas buscando que sean estaticos entonces usarias la palabra reservada `static` asi:

```
public static void guardarEnArchivo(Vector<PadreDeMiClase> toSave, File archivo){
   /*codigo*/
}
public static Vector<PadreDeMiClase> leerDesdeArchivo(File archivo) {
   /*codigo*/
}
```

En teoría de programación orientada a objetos (POO), podes encontrar que al hacer esto, todas tus clases `nombreDeMiClase` tienen la **capacidad** o también **son instancias** de `PadreDeMiClase` esto quiere decir que en todos los sitios en donde se espere a `PadreDeMiClase` (funciones, variables y demas) entonces podrás enviar una instancia de los hijos. A esto se le conoce como polimorfismo en POO.

Si deseas hacer una prueba rápida, podes parametrizar con `Object` los vectores de tus funciones. Esto te dará un efecto similar, puesto que Java es Full POO y tiene una jerarquia de clases, en las que todas las clases (hasta las creadas por vos) heredan de `Object` cuando a estas no le especificas un padre usando la palabra reservada extends.

**UNA OBSERVACION:**

Si tenés pensado hacer que esas funciones sean métodos `static` entonces no podes usar miembros **no estaticos** en dichas clases. Un ejemplo de esto, es tu linea de codigo: `this.toFill.addElement(tmp);` el miembro toFill es no `static`, en resumen todo lo que podas referenciar con this, no se puede usar en funciones `static`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Servio... En realidad el problema es que al intentar implementarlo con clases que representan tablas tan diferentes, es complicado hacer herencia... Esa había sido mi primer salida, pero se complicó conforme avanzó el proyecto...
Referente al this.toFill se me escapó ya que había copiado de uno de los códigos ya implementados para tratar de ejemplificar el método genérico...

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu tiempo, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si a alguien le es útil, el problema se solucionó implementando los métodos de la siguiente manera:

```
public static <T> void saveToFile(Vector<T> toSave, File archivo) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            for(int i=0; i<toSave.size(); i++) {
                oos.writeObject(toSave.elementAt(i));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) { try { oos.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
            if (fos != null) { try { fos.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Vector<T> loadFromFile(File archivo) {
        Object tmp;
        Vector<T> toLoad = new Vector<T>();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            do {
                tmp =  ois.readObject();
                if (tmp != null) {
                    toLoad.addElement((T) tmp);
                }
                
            } while (tmp != null);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ois != null) { try { ois.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
            if (fis != null) { try { fis.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {} }
        }
        return toLoad;
    }
```