# Parámetro formal de max de Collections

Tags: java

El parámetro formal de Collections.max es:

```
max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Yo entiendo que significa que puedes pasar como argumento todas las colecciones con clases T o subclases de esta, pero si coge el tipo cuando se pasa la colección, por ejemplo, un ArrayList, ¿por qué utiliza el comodín ? extends? El parámetro `Collection<T>` debería funcionar, ¿o no?

Comment: Hola Kevin!, te pido porfavor expliques de manera mas concreta tu duda para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Yo creo que se utiliza el comodín porque el compilador no sabe exactamente el tipo de parametro concreto que va a recibir y se tiene que resolver en tiempo de ejecución. Por ejemplo T podría ser así.. `T extends Number`. Yo creo que es mas o menos a lo que te refieres.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Tipo de dato genérico en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33563/tipo-de-dato-gen%c3%a9rico-en-java)